# Is there any Editor in which I click on a line and it takes me to its definition defined in another page

Tags: xcode, eclipse, editor, feature-file

I am working in a mobile app testing project. We do write feature files (like scenarios) in a simple Xcode editor as of now. What I want is if I click on any step written in my feature file, it should take me to its step definition which is written in another document and open that in that editor.
I don't know if this facility is available with Xcode editor but if it is, please let me know how I can use it.
Also I thought if Eclipse or any of its plugin could be used but I don't know how.

Please let me know if there is any Editor which could be used for that (selecting an step and it takes me to the page where it is defined). And also it should be able to get executed on my mac with terminal.

Thank you very much for any help. really!

P.S. I am using git (SourceTree, Xcode etc) and working for an iOS app.

Comment: Post a "line" example here ...

Comment: For example "Given the App is running"  - this is one step which is defined in another document (step definitions), so when I click on my above line, it should take me to the stepdefiniton document where it is defined OR at least display the definition as a tag when I hover on that step. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you use standard XCTest framework for testing? The feature you're looking for is present in Calabash framework. See tutorial at https://www.natashatherobot.com/calabash-ios-tutorial/